# JavaFX TableView's header height

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, fxml

In my JavaFX app I want to create table. I'm using TableView. I want it to fit exactly 5 items. 
So what I did is this:

```
table.fixedCellSizeProperty().bind(table.heightProperty().divide(6));
```

The problem is that header row of my table doesn't change its height. It fits label inside it.
I tried this approach, but I get null value from lookup if I call this in initialize method of my controller:

```
Pane header = (Pane) table.lookup("TableHeaderRow");   
header.prefHeightProperty().bind(table.heightProperty().divide(6));
```

So, question is: How can I bind height of header row? Thank you!

Comment: the header is only available after the tableView gets its skin which is when it is added to the scene - so you can listen to the skin property and do the binding in the listener

Comment: You mean how to change height of columns?

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful also

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is nearly correct, you only have to set the header height when the skin is available, i.e. (as hinted by kleopatra):

```
table.skinProperty().addListener((obs, ol, ne) -> {
    Pane header = (Pane) table.lookup("TableHeaderRow");   
    header.prefHeightProperty().bind(table.heightProperty().divide(6));
});
```